# How can i run exe installer from an angular2/4

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, browser, console

My requirement is to minimize the browser window by clicking on some button. I see it's not possible in js.

I found the solution that we can minimize the browser window in C# console app.

anybody have an idea about calling the exe installer from angular2 or how can i minimize the browser window in angular2.

I don't want the restore the size of browser window i want to minimize the browser window

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"window.minimize()"` javascript function.